# list of figures space between number and text

Tags: spacing

I need more space between the number and the text in my list of figures. How can I adjust it? I renewcommand to get A.Abb. 1 because the figure is in my appendix. In my list of figures it doesn´t fit with the A.Abb. so I need more space there.

```
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.Abb.\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{irf_sp_crix_tag}
    \caption{Impuls-Antwort-Folge: CRIX S\&P500 Tag}\label{IRF_SP_CRIX_TAG}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{irf_crix_eur_usd}
    \caption{Impuls-Antwort-Folge: CRIX EUR/USD Woche}\label{IRF_eur_usd_crix_woche}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) without all the stray \ signs?

Comment: @samcarter is it better now? can you understand my problem or do you need further information. Sorry I am quite new in the forum so please excuse my beginner mistakes

Answer (score 5):

Use the `tocloft` package (although as you don't say what class you are using the funcions may be already provided by the class by e.g., `memoir.cls`).

In your preamble put:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}% change 4em to suit
```

which will provide 4em for the width of the caption number in the LoF.

See the manual (`> texdoc tocloft`) for more information.

Comment: it works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for